# set an image from gallery for background of desktop phone (android-java)

Tags: java, android, background, gallery, slideshow

I have one app that like a Slide show or gallery but i want when anybody use this app be able to set the image to background on android phone

the app can show image i just want to able set image to background - and its can be enough if i can set address of image in Variable and then i can use this Code

```
WallpaperManager wpm = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
try {
    wpm.setResource(R.drawable.image_1);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple tutorial for it. visit this [link](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/set-an-image-as-wallpaper-in-android/) And if you have imagePath then use following code as :-

```
is = new FileInputStream(new File(imagePath));
bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
Bitmap useThisBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(
    bitmap, parent.getWidth(), parent.getHeight(), true);
bitmap.recycle();
if(imagePath!=null){        
    wallpaperManager = WallpaperManager.getInstance(this);
    wallpaperDrawable = wallpaperManager.getDrawable();
    wallpaperManager.setBitmap(useThisBitmap);
    }
```